# var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP)); not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

codes here:

```
<?php
include_once('PDOconnect.mysql.php');
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pwd) or die('mysql connection failed');
$query = "select * from tb_user";
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
var_dump($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP));
?>
```

output here:

```
array(3) {
    [1]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "tomorrow"
    }
    [2]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "xiaoming"
    }
    [3]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "xiaoming"
    }
}
```

The table

```
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| id | user     | pwd     | createtime          | address               |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | tomorrow | 111     | 2015-06-20 18:10:02 | Adelaide              |
|  2 | xiaoming | 222     | 2020-04-08 18:30:02 | Unknown city          |
|  3 | xiaoming | 1112131 | 2020-04-08 21:40:12 | Where                 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm mad with it
Thank you very much if you can rescue me from becoming desperated

Comment: There should be more in the array! As expected the data should be sorted by id, but in fact there is id printed only.

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Fetch flags aren't meant for sorting. Can you specify your desired output? Currently it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do - fetch a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works correctly.

As [said](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-parameters) - `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP`  is used to:

> To return an associative array grouped by the values of a specified column

In your case - first selected column is `id`, so your data is grouped by `id` and `id` value is **array key**.

And according to [**this comment**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php#120642):

> By default, results are grouped by first column (index 0) and second column (index 1) is returned

In your case - first column it is `id` and second column is `user`. So again - everything is **correct**.